# Sidebar height with variable page content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In wordpress I'm making a website with a sidebar at the left side of it.
So, first comes up the header and then my sidebar at the left side.

The problem is that my sidebar is as long as my content is, so it's not to the bottom of my page and a white field stays at the bottom:

My html sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<ul class="ulsidebar">
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="home">Home</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">6</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">7</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">8</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">9</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">10</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">11</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">12</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">13</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">14</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">15</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">16</a></li>
<li class="lisidebar"><a class="linksidebar" href="#">17</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    z-index:            10;
    border-top:         2px #000000; 
    position:           absolute;
    top:                25%;
    bottom:             0;
    left:               0;
    width:              15%;
    height:             100%;
    background:         #C6A970;
}

.ulsidebar {
    margin-top:         20%;
    color:              #ffffff;
}

.lisidebar {
    padding:            8px;
}

.linksidebar, .afooter {
    text-decoration:    none; 
    color:              #ffffff;
}

.linksidebar:hover, .afooter:hover {
    text-decoration:    none;
    color:              #000000;
}

.content {
    position:           relative;
    margin-left:        10%;
    height:             100%;
    min-height:         100% !important;
}
```

The content class is for the content next to my sidebar.
Fixed will not help for me, because there is a white space above it with the header.

This is how it looks like:

```
         HEADER
---|---------------------
S  |
I  |
D  |     CONTENT
E  |
B  |
A  |
R  |
-------------------------
WHITE GAB
-------------------------
   |
---|---------------------
        FOOTER
```

Does anyone have suggestions to complete my sidebar? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this in action?

Comment: This is what I got now. Content is the block next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using this CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    padding-bottom: 5000px;
    margin-bottom:  -5000px;
    overflow:       hidden;
 }
```

This works for me.
Everyone, thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

give the 100% height to sidebar 
or set some height

Comment: When I do this, the size doesn't change. I still have the white gab, between my content and the footer.

Comment: On my webpage, is 100% somewhere in the middle of my page. That's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So if will do your sidebar parent div with position Fixed and top:0 and bottom:0, it will go from top to bottom, something like this:

```
div {
position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 180px;
    left:0;
}
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/nk64k09q/

Comment: I've tried this, but there's a header above my sidebar. So that's why I can't use position fixed. That's why I am looking for something with position: absolute or relative.

Comment: Why not to write top: 60 px; (if your header is 60 px...) check this:https://jsfiddle.net/nk64k09q/1/

Comment: aah, yes. But if I go scrolling down, my sidebar goes over my header. ;)